# is generating a random value n times the same as generating a large amount of values and randomly choosing n of them?

Tags: statistics, computer-science, binomial-distribution, python

I'm fairly sure that it's the same but I just wanted to make sure, since a lot of stuff about statistics are counterintuitive

is this code

```
from scipy.stats import binom
distribution = binom(1000, 0.23, 0)
ls = []
for i in range(200000):
    ls.append( int( distribution.rvs() ) )
```

the same as

```
from scipy.stats import binom
from random import random
distribution = binom(1000, 0.23, 0)
values = distribution.rvs(size=1000000)

for i in range(200000):
    ls.append( int(values[int(random()*len(values) - 1)]) )
```

Thanks

Comment: same in what sense. I think in both cases, the empirical distribution would converge to the true distribution at the same rate

Comment: as in, would the generated values be roughly the same? I've heard that given a large enough sample it's going to look like a normal distribution curve but I'm not sure if stuff like "binomial distribution is not memoryless" would affect the results

Answer (score 0):

I do think it is the same. It would not be the same if you were to generate $n$ values (one time) but whenever it chose one, that same number could not be chosen again.

But since there can be repeated values, I truly think it is the same. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks! I've read that binomial distribution is not memoryless like exponential distribution, would that affect the results?